# Get string between string/ and /

Tags: regex

Ive been trying for ages to get the id `30393` from the below string.

`https://example.com/service_requests/30393/journey`

Any ideas how? Its the `/` causing me issues. Been trying `(?<=/).*?(?=/)` but obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Is it always the number before the last `/`? Just split the string into an array.

Comment: Try escaping `(?<=\/).*?(?=\/)`

Comment: Does it have to be done with a regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

`\d+`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/9JyTdx/1

**OR**

`(?<=service_requests\/)\d+(?=\/journey)`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/8SXJiJ/1

Answer (score 1):

```
/^https:\/\/example.com\/service_requests\/(\d*)\/journey$/
```

Comment: And if that's not right then your question is wrong.

Comment: Excellent. This doesn't involve anything fancy and does what it says it does.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is this `(?<=service_requests\/).*?(?=\/)`

Some of the comments inspired me. Just made an alteration to @bhusak comment.

Answer (score 1):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Split the string on `/` characters and return the 2nd-to-last element. Here's the JavaScript solution, but it should be similar in other languages.

```js
let url = 'https://example.com/service_requests/30393/journey';
let arr = url.split('/');
let id = arr[arr.length-2];
console.log(id);
```

Comment: This is not regex syntax.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True. I'll delete if he answers the question in my comment in the affirmative.

Comment: It might not be a regex, but it's not worth a downvote.

Comment: @3limin4t0r It's OK, I need to be put in my place every now and then....

Comment: @3limin4t0r Wrong answers get downvotes not my fault. Question clearly states regex. No Javascript mentioned even once. I concede it's a bad question and at the very least a regex engine/variant should have been stated. But still no Javascript. Barmar knows this, despite his sarcastic attempt to get personal...